# VB.net windows service works fine when ran as an exe but does nothing when installed as service

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-services

I've created an SNMP listener application for one of our servers that runs as a service and passively listens for any SNMP message alerts sent from another server, and when one is received is sends out a page/email to appropriate staff.  I followeda few online tutorials for setting up the application as a windows service since it needs to run constantly and won't require input/interaction from a user, or interaction with any GUI/desktop applications.

For some reason, when I install the application as a service, it installs correctly, but doesn't actually seem to be working.  When SNMP messages are sent to the server nothing happens.  However, in my app.publish folder there's an SNMPTrapper.exe application,and if I run that exe on its own, then everything works fine.  For the time being I'm using a workaround so that the Onstart section of the code for the service basically just launches the SNMPTrapper.exe application, and when the service is stopped, it finds and kills the SNMPTrapper.exe process.  At this point though, the service itself doesn't seem to be working/doing anything.  It's essentially just a way to get the SNMPTrapper.exe application launched.

Does anyone know what the issue may be?  In some of the tutorials I've read through they outline how to setup polling intervals for the service, but I don't think that would be applicable since this service will essentially just run constantly to listen for new messages, it won't need to check for anything at a regular interval.

Right now pretty much all of my code is executed in Sub Main() except for a few function calls.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t state how you’re doing any of this. For a windows service you get two messages from the system: OnStart and OnStop. The job of OnStart is to set up all the required code to do the job, then exit. It doesn’t take part in the work so you need a Task or Thread setting up to do that. The Task or Thread should loop until it gets a message, passed by OnStop, that we’re done. If you want a service that you can test from the command line then your Main routine needs to do exactly the same setup, then wait for a key to be pressed before sending an OnStop.
(As an aside, you ARE remembering to start the service once you have installed it?)

Comment: Yes, I've made sure the service is started once I've installed it.  It sounds like the issue is that I should probably take the code I have in Main and put it into a function that I can call, then call that function as a task in my OnStart method.  At that point the task will run and stay active until the OnStop event ends it.